# how to set orientation for each scene in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation

I have 4 scenes in my game
I need to set scene 1 and scene 3 in landscape mode, scene 2 and scene 4 in portrait mode 
how can I do this?
please help me out...
I'm searching for a long time but couldn't find out the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can have a script that checks for the actual level and changes the orientation in according to the retrieved value.

As an example:

```
function Start(){
    if (Application.LoadedLevel == 1)
       Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    else if (Application.LoadedLevel == 2)
       Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    //...
}
```

More info about [usage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html) and [orientation values](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since around Unity 5.3 there is a new API for getting the current scene.
This example forces the screen orientation on mobile devices to portrait on a scene called "GameView" and landscape otherwise.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ScreenOrientationScript : MonoBehaviour {
  void Start () {
    if (Application.isMobilePlatform == true) {
      if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "GameView") {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
      } else {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;       
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample iOS setting to allow orientations
[image: iOS Seeting for allowed orientations]

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses **single/sole** activity for **ALL** Levels/Scenes, which is com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity, as can be found in AndroidManifest.xml file.

So all you need do is to specify the orientation in the Player Setting Inspector (Default Orientation part):

[image]